# How to Sort element with object null in Spring Data Jpa

Tags: java, spring, sorting, spring-data-jpa, sql-order-by

I have two entity below:

```
@Entity
public class Task {
...
@ManyToOne
private User user;
...
}

@Entity
public class User {
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "task")
private Set<Task> task;
...
}
```

How can I using Sort to Sort Task by firstName of User with User is null on top ?

I have try `Sort.by(Sort.Order.asc("user.firstName").nullsFirst());`
But I got the error: NullpointerException

Comment: Share your code and related stacktrace. What you provided here is not enough to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

You can create something like this.

```
Criteria criteria = ...;
criteria.addOrder( Order.asc( "firstName" ).nulls(NullPrecedence.FIRST) );
```

for more information you can check this documentation.

[NullPrecedence](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/javadocs/org/hibernate/NullPrecedence.html)